# Is it possible to split EditText with "/" to create a date?

Tags: android, date, android-edittext

I'd like to create an EditText that allows user to quickly put in a specific date in format dd/mm/yy, where he only needs to pass day, month and year numbers, without worrying about slashes and overall formating. Is it possible to do that with one EditText or is my only option to create multiple EditTexts and jump the cursor between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the date mask "##/##/##" in your EditText. Here is a tutorial on how to do this:

https://medium.com/@diegoy_kuri/masks-in-android-edit-text-fields-33a2fd47f1af

Comment: Thats not exactly what I was looking for, but it works okay, so I can use that. Thanks for fast answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could solve these by :

1. Add `addTextChangedListener` to your editText
2. Inside `afterTextChanged` function, add logic to append '/' after user put day and month

By this way, you will get same result for date that displayed to user and date that your code record.